# Toggle join/leave in irssi

Tags: irssi

I run irssi on a screen session on a remote server<sup>1</sup>. This way I'm always online and can catch pings, among other things.

I know that in irssi I can set `/IGNORE` directives to hide all joins/parts/quits, however that only works for incoming messages. The old messages stay stuck on the screen. I'd prefer not to permanently ignore everything as I prefer keeping the join/part messages on when I'm online.

Now, if I go offline and come back later, there's a flood of blue join/part messages but not so much conversation. Is there any way I can toggle the blue messages — the ones that have already been received — on and off? This way I can quickly skim through the conversation and look for important stuff.

<sup>1. I don't have much of a choice, there's a blanket port ban in the institute so I just run irssi on the server where I do my other testing.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is crapbuster which does something similar.

```
crapbuster.pl - irssi::scripts
scripts.irssi.org/scripts/crapbuster.pl‎
# By Stefan 'tommie' Tomanek
```